# Primefaces Datatable NullPointerException when changing number rows per page

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a datatable setup to display 5,10,15,20,25 rows per page.

When we toggle between 5 and 10, datatable is working as intended. However, if we toggle 15 and above this error will be produced.

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/webquote].[Faces Servlet]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.createPartialResponseWriter(PartialViewContextImpl.java:441) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.access$300(PartialViewContextImpl.java:71) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$DelayedInitPartialResponseWriter.getWrapped(PartialViewContextImpl.java:582) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at javax.faces.context.PartialResponseWriter.startDocument(PartialResponseWriter.java:115) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startDocument(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:133) [primefaces-3.5.20.jar:3.5.20]
at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:199) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:123) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79) [primefaces-3.5.20.jar:3.5.20]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
at com.avnet.emasia.webquote.web.security.SetupSecurityContextFilter.doFilter(SetupSecurityContextFilter.java:68) [classes:]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237) [spring-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167) [spring-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
```

Sometimes it will just return this error when the page is displayed. In other occasions, the page will load perfectly, but NPE occurs when user click on a row.

This is a huge datatable with about 100 columns.

Is there a limitation to how many columns in a datatable that Primefaces can display properly?

Comment: Stack trace tells that an exception occurred, but the exception handler itself in turn failed to properly handle the exception. If you debug/fix/replace the exception handler, then you'll be able to see the *actual* exception causing all this trouble. OmniFaces `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` may come into rescue. Related reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901882/java-lang-illegalstateexception-cdata-tags-may-not-nest/17946483#17946483

Comment: Being it a PF related exception, can you provide its version?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. 

Xtreme Biker: We are using Primefaces 3.5.8 and recently upgraded to 3.5.20. All issues persists through out the different versions.

BalusC: I will explore OmniFaces FullAjaxExceptionHandler to find out the root cause of the problem, thanks for dropping in.

Comment: @BalusC I followed your suggestion and applied OmniFaces FullAjaxExceptionHandler and from there it shows that the no of parameters in my HTTP Post request exceeds my server limit (JBOSS). 

By increasing the max parameter as such in Standalone.xml

        `<system-properties>
        <property name="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.MAX_COUNT" value="2000"/>
    </system-properties>`

I have been able to resolve my issue. Thanks