# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SortFeature.multiSort

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm always getting an exception when I try to sort my primefaces datatable:

```
16:28:01,771 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8099-3) Error Rendering View[/pages/requests.xhtml]: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SortFeature.multiSort(SortFeature.java:173) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SortFeature.encode(SortFeature.java:104) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:78) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.9.Final.jar:2.0.9.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.9.Final.jar:2.0.9.Final]
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:517) [jsf-impl-2.1.16-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183) [jsf-impl-2.1.16-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:821) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.9.Final.jar:2.0.9.Final]
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:378) [jsf-impl-2.1.16-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:298) [jsf-impl-2.1.16-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:60) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:979) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.9.Final.jar:2.0.9.Final]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.9.Final.jar:2.0.9.Final]
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:411) [jsf-impl-2.1.16-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124) [jsf-impl-2.1.16-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:286) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.9.Final.jar:2.0.9.Final]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120) [jsf-impl-2.1.16-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.16-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.16-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.9.Final.jar:2.0.9.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:897) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:626) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:2039) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]

16:28:01,818 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/ecad-web].[Faces Servlet]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8099-3) Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: CDATA tags may not nest
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlResponseWriter.startCDATA(HtmlResponseWriter.java:664) [jsf-impl-2.1.16-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at javax.faces.context.ResponseWriterWrapper.startCDATA(ResponseWriterWrapper.java:172) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.9.Final.jar:2.0.9.Final]
at javax.faces.context.PartialResponseWriter.startError(PartialResponseWriter.java:342) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.9.Final.jar:2.0.9.Final]
at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startError(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:190) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:200) [jsf-impl-2.1.16-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:124) [jsf-impl-2.1.16-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119) [jsf-impl-2.1.16-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.16-jbossorg-1.jar:]
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.9.Final.jar:2.0.9.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:897) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:626) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:2039) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
```

I've read,

- [applying sorting in p:datatable but getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: CDATA tags may not nest when click for sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263026/applying-sorting-in-pdatatable-but-getting-java-lang-illegalstateexception-cda)

and checked the comment: "You've 2 problems: 1) bad ajax exception handling 2) doing business logic during render response. –  BalusC"
-> This isn't the case. There shouldn't be any exception to start with and I'm not doing any business logic in the getter.

xhtml code:

```
<p:dataTable id="pendingRequests" var="pendingRequest"
             value="#{requestBean.pendingRequests}"
             rows="5"
             paginator="true"
             rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,20,50"
             sortMode="multiple">

    <p:column style="width:16px">
        <p:rowToggler />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Reference"  sortBy="#{pendingRequest.requestReference}">
        <h:outputText value="#{pendingRequest.requestReference}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:rowExpansion>
        <p:panelGrid  columns="2" columnClasses="label,value" >
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputLabel value="Details" />
            </f:facet>

            <h:outputText value="Reference: " />
            <h:outputText value="#{pendingRequest.requestReference}" />
        </p:panelGrid>

        <br/>
        <p:dataTable var="pendingRequestDocument"
                     value="#{pendingRequest.pendingRequestDocuments}">

            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputLabel value="Documents" />
            </f:facet>

            <p:column headerText="Stored document">
                <h:outputText value="#{pendingRequestDocument.storedDocument}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
        <br/><br/>
    </p:rowExpansion>
</p:dataTable>
```

Backingbean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import be.fgov.health.ecad.domain.request.PendingRequest;
import be.fgov.health.ecad.service.RequestService;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class RequestBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6538980904680369808L;
    private List<PendingRequest> pendingRequests;

    @Inject
    private RequestService requestService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        pendingRequests = requestService.findAllPendingRequests();
    }

    public List<PendingRequest> getPendingRequests() {
        return pendingRequests;

    }
}
```

I've tried debugging the getPendingRequests and it's never null (but it is invoked multiple times but that's normal behaviour..).

Has anyone got any idea?

- JSF version: 2.0
- PrimeFaces version: 5.2

EDIT:
For testing purposes, I just created a new `List` in the getter (without calling some EJB) and I've got the same exception.

Comment: Is this exception also caused without the external API being used - `be.fgov.health.*`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.IllegalStateException: CDATA tags may not nest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901882/java-lang-illegalstateexception-cdata-tags-may-not-nest)

Comment: You say you you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263026/applying-sorting-in-pdatatable-but-getting-java-lang-illegalstateexception-cda, but did you  read the duplicate this question was linked to? You have an AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl exception in your stacktrace. You need to find out what the actual contents of that exception are; "CDATA tags may not nest" has practically nothing to do with your error. Use Chrome Dev Tools or similar to check the actual contents of the AJAX request response.

Comment: There must have been something wrong with my test data.. I've delete everything and put some other test data in it and now it seems to be working. I don't know the cause unfortunately..

Comment: Forgot changing serialVersionUID and had old data being being deserialised into the bean?

Comment: @SyrenBaran that might indeed be the case... :)

Answer (score 0):

The IllegalStateException is most likely a red herring. I have encountered similiar behavior with primefaces as well. This happens as far as i can tell when an Exception occurs during an ajax call.

You have to solve the root cause, the NullPointerException. Possibly you have `null`-values for `pendingRequest.requestReference`.

Comment: I've checked against the DB and the reference is never null. And as you can see in the edit, I've created my own objects in the getter and I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Hmm, so it blows on `for(SortMeta meta : sortMeta) {`. Are you sure `PendingRequest.requestReference` is [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) ?