# failed invocation of init method, Error in managed bean creation

Tags: spring, jsf, nullpointerexception, autowired, postconstruct

I am actually working on a Jsf project with spring Ioc and primefaces.
when i run my project i obtain this error and i couldn't really find out why. this is the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.grh.bean.TypePrimeManager.init(TypePrimeManager.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:346)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:132)
    ... 63 more
```

this is my managed bean:

```
package com.grh.bean;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.grh.model.Input;
import com.grh.model.TypPrime;
import com.grh.service.TypeprimeServ;

@Component
@ManagedBean
@Scope("session")
public class TypePrimeManager{
    @Autowired
    private TypeprimeServ TPS;
    private List<TypPrime> tprimes =new ArrayList<TypPrime>();
    private TypPrime selectedtype=new TypPrime();
    private TypPrime Pr=new TypPrime();
    private TypPrime P=new TypPrime();
    private List<Input> inputs;
    private boolean a=false;
    private TypPrime MTypepPrime= new TypPrime();
    private List<TypPrime> listTypajouter;
    private List<TypPrime> listexistantajout;
    private int nbrechampafficher;
    private int nbchamps;
    private String nb=null;
    private TypPrime typSup =new TypPrime();
    private List<TypPrime> listTypePrime;
    private int n;
    private String[] TypeEntr;



    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        listTypePrime.clear();
        listTypePrime = TPS.TousTypePrime();  
        }


    public int getN() {
        return n;
    }


    public void setN(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }


    public void setInputs(List<Input> inputs) {
        this.inputs = inputs;
    }


    public List<TypPrime> getListTypePrime() {
        return listTypePrime;
    }

    public void setListTypePrime(List<TypPrime> listTypePrime) {
        this.listTypePrime = listTypePrime;
    }


    public String getNb() {
        return nb;
    }


    public void setNb(String nb) {
        this.nb = nb;
    }

    public TypPrime getSelectedtype() {
        return selectedtype;
    }


    public void setSelectedtype(TypPrime selectedtype) {
        this.selectedtype = selectedtype;
    }

    public int getNbchamps() {
        return nbchamps;
    }

    public void setNbchamps(int nbchamps) {
        this.nbchamps = nbchamps;
    }


    public int getNbrechampafficher() {
        return nbrechampafficher;
    }


    public void setNbrechampafficher(int nbrechampafficher) {
        this.nbrechampafficher = nbrechampafficher;
    }


    public TypPrime getMTypepPrime() {
        return MTypepPrime;
    }


    public void setMTypepPrime(TypPrime mTypepPrime) {
        MTypepPrime = mTypepPrime;
    }



public String remplirList(){

    listTypePrime.addAll(TPS.TousTypePrime());
    return "";
}


public TypPrime getTypSup() {
    return typSup;
}

public void setTypSup(TypPrime typSup) {
    this.typSup = typSup;
}



    public TypPrime getPr() {
    return Pr;
}

public void setPr(TypPrime pr) {
    Pr = pr;
}


public List<TypPrime> getTprimes() {
    return tprimes;
}


public void setTprimes(List<TypPrime> tprimes) {
    this.tprimes = tprimes;
}

public TypPrime getP() {
    return P;
}


public void setP(TypPrime p) {
    P = p;
}


    public TypeprimeServ getTPS() {
        return TPS;
    }

    public void setTPS(TypeprimeServ tPS) {
        TPS = tPS;
    }

    public List<TypPrime> gettprimes() {
        return tprimes;
    }

    public void settprimes(List<TypPrime> Tprimes) {
        tprimes = Tprimes;
    }


    public boolean isA() {
        return a;
    }


    public void setA(boolean a) {
        this.a = a;
    }


    public String[] getTypeEntr() {
        return TypeEntr;
    }


    public void setTypeEntr(String[] typeEntr) {
        TypeEntr = typeEntr;
    }


    public void traitementAjout(){


    }

    public List<TypPrime> getListTypajouter() {
        return listTypajouter;
    }


    public void setListTypajouter(List<TypPrime> listTypajouter) {
        this.listTypajouter = listTypajouter;
    }


    public List<TypPrime> getListexistantajout() {
        return listexistantajout;
    }


    public void setListexistantajout(List<TypPrime> listexistantajout) {
        this.listexistantajout = listexistantajout;
    }




    public void traitmenetModifer(){


    }
    public void traitementSupprimer(){

        try{
             TPS.supprimerTypeprime(typSup);
             FacesContext co = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
             co.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("type de prime bien supprimé"));
             init();
             selectedtype=null;

        }catch(Exception e){
                 FacesContext co = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
                 co.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"Type de prime non supprimé car déjà utilisé", null));
                 remplirList();
                 RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("carsTable");
            }       

    }

    public void champs(){
        setTypeEntr(new String[n]);
        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.execute("PF('ajoutertypeprime').show()");

    }
    public void add() {
            Input input = new Input();
            input.setLabel("Input " + (inputs.size() + 1));
            inputs.add(input);
        }

        public List<Input> getInputs() {
            return inputs;
        }
        public void supPrimeType(){ 
            typSup=selectedtype;
            RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
            context.execute("PF('dialogSupprimer').show()");
            selectedtype=null;

        }       

}
```

and  this my application context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" >
      <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>

        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/grh"></property>

        <!-- property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.3/grh"></property-->

        <property name="username" value="root"></property>
        <property name="password" value="root"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource"><ref bean="dataSource" /></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
               <props>
                   <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
               </props>
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>                                                                                                                      
            <value>com.grh.model.Typecredit</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.GroupetravailEmploye</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.Mission</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.Organisme</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.Poste</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.Etablissement</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.TypPrime</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.Ville</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.Credit</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.Configuration</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.ExceptionDisponibilite</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.Echelon</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.TypeSanction</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.PosteEmploye</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.Contrat</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.Grade</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.FormationEmploye</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.HeureExceptionnelle</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.Groupetravail</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.Administration</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.Prime</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.Conjoint</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.MissionEmploye</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.TypPrimeEchelon</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.Diplome</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.GradeEmploye</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.Sanction</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.Document</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.Echelle</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.EmployeHeureExceptionnelle</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.Typeconge</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.TypeRetraite</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.ConjointEmploye</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.Typecontrat</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.Formation</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.DiplomePoste</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.Droit</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.Conge</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.PrimeEmploye</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.Employe</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.Enfant</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.DiplomePersonnelle</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.Typerecrutement</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.Pays</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.Retraite</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.TypeCreditEtablissement</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.DiplomeEtablissement</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.OrganismeEtablissement</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.TypcongeEtablissement</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.TypContratEtablissement</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.TypRecrutementEtablissement</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.TypSanctionEtablissement</value>
            <value>com.grh.model.TypretraiteEtabl</value></list>
        </property></bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.grh"/>
</beans>
```

I realy appreciate any Help.

Comment: Try and take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901882/java-lang-illegalstateexception-cdata-tags-may-not-nest you must be experiencing the same

Comment: the problem is your `@ManagedBean` is also a `@Component`. When instantiated by spring (due to the `@Component` everything will work, however when instantiated by JSF (due to the `@ManagedBean`) the `@Autowire` is useless as it works only for a spring managed bean. You have 2 instances of the same class. For JSF it would also be a singleton as it doesn't know anything about the `@Scope` from spring. In short your approach isn't going to work. Either make it a fully JSF bean or Spring bean but don't mix.

Comment: @jmcg thank you guys for help. I found the error: 
the error was in the init method, i did not noticed that i empty a list that is not already created.


` @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        listTypePrime.clear();
        listTypePrime = TPS.TousTypePrime();  
        }

so that's what cause the NPE.