# java.lang.IllegalStateException: CDATA tags may not nest error in pe:keyFilter

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I'm getting error in pe:keyFilter,
java.lang.IllegalStateException: CDATA tags may not nest

```
 <pe:keyFilter for="inputText" mask="num" id="keyfilternum" />
```

I'm using Primefaces 5.2 and Primefaces-Extensions 3.0.0

Comment: The probable culprit could be business logic in a getter method. [See for details](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17946483/1391249).

Comment: The exception you're currently seeing is not your root problem, but it is hiding away the **real** exception. The duplicate tells how to get a hand of the real exception. This way you can ask/search on exactly that exception.

Comment: If I remove pe:keyFilter then there is no problem but if I add pe:keyFilter then again I get cdata error

Comment: I found solution, the solution is to use Primefaces 5.1 version